# SELECT limiting to only results based on a CSV list from a separate table

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables, mutual-exclusion

So I have a list of CSVs in one table. (EG:  `1,3,19` ) 
I want to search out all of the usernames from the other table where the ids match any of those.

I feel like I should be able to do something like:

```
<?
$query = "SELECT player_ids FROM cast_list WHERE game='".$gameid."' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$playerquery = "SELECT username,id FROM players WHERE id IN (".$result.") ORDER BY username;
$player_result = mysql_query($playerquery) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($player_result) ) {
  echo "<li>".$row['username']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example doesn't work because your need to get the value of the column player_ids from the $result resource using one of mysql_fetch_* methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) (which will be faster):

```
$playerquery = "SELECT username,id 
                FROM players 
                WHERE id IN (SELECT player_ids FROM cast_list WHERE game='".$gameid."') 
                ORDER BY username";
```

Btw if `game` is an integer field you don't have put quotes (`'` `'`) around the value.

Comment: I believe the OP is indicating that `player_ids` is a CSV of player ids.  So this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is correct, but you need to transfer the `$result` to an actual string array:

```
$game_ids = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
 $game_ids[] = .$row[1];
}
```

Now using `implode` to convert the array to a  comma separated values with a comma:

```
$playerquery = "SELECT username,id FROM players WHERE id IN (" . implode(",",$result) . ") ORDER BY username;
```

Comment: `implode(",",$game_ids)`